# Send image from camera to Android webview

Tags: javascript, android, file-upload

I have an architecture where I am having a webview in MainActivity of my Android app. A page having a "Take Photo" button loads whenever user opens the app. On clicking "Take Photo" button, javascript will call `dispatchTakePictureIntent()` method defined in the Android app, which will redirect user to the Camera. Once, the user clicks the photo and submits it, I want to send the photo back to JS which in turn will make a AJAX call to the server to store the image.

I am facing trouble in developing the flow once user submits the photo. In my current implementation, I am able to store the image file locally and retrieve a file path, but I am unable to figure out how to use this file path in JS to get the file and send it on the server. Kindly help me out with this.

I have taken reference from this article: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskPath

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String FILE_PATH_PREFIX = "file:";

    private String imageFilePath;
    private String callbackFunction;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidPlatform.setUp(this, APPLICATION_NAME);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath(getFilesDir().getPath());
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("URL to the page having take photo button");
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void dispatchTakePictureIntent(String _callbackFunction) {
        this.callbackFunction = _callbackFunction;

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

            File photoFile = createImageFile();
            if (photoFile != null) {
                this.imageFilePath = FILE_PATH_PREFIX + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                        "com.example.fileprovider",
                        photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.please_retry, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.no_camera_found, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "storephoto_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = null;
        try {
            image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg", storageDir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception in createImageFile:", e);
        }
        return image;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && callbackFunction != null && imageFilePath != null) {
                // What to do with imageFilePath?
                //
                // How to use it in Javascript to read and send image to backend server?
                //
                // Sample code if we send imageFilePath to JS:
                // String callbackModule = String.format(TAKE_PICTURE_JS_MODULE, callbackFunction, imageFilePath);
                // webView.evaluateJavascript(callbackModule, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Javascript

```
$takePhotoButton.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Android && Android.dispatchTakePictureIntent("takePhotoCallbackFn");
});
```

**Note:** *Here it is necessary that user submits the photo through camera only and not via choosing/uploading an existing file.*

Comment: you can convert to base64 string and send it using POST or GET

Comment: @MufaddalHamid where should the conversion take place? In Android or in JS?

Comment: Actually I am not an android dev so I don't know that but you must do this from where you have opened WebView